# Is it a bad design to return a partial view that only contains a java script alert in my asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following Action method that return an `_error` partial view in case an Exception occur:-

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Register(string id, int classid) {
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        User user = r.FindUser(id);
        Users_Classes uc = new Users_Classes();
        uc.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
        uc.ClassID = classid;
        user.Users_Classes.Add(uc);
        r.Save();
        ViewBag.classid = classid;
        return PartialView("_usersearch2", uc);
    }
    catch (DataException ex)
    { 
        return PartialView("_error");
    }
```

and the following `_error` partial view:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('The user might have been already Assinged, Search Again to get the latest users');
</script>
```

The above approach is working fine, but does it consider a bad design to return a partial view to  display only an alert ? and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are now tying your implementation to your user interface. The Controller suddenly decides how an error message should appear on the client.

What if you want to change it from an alert to displaying a red border around a text input with some description next to it?

Determining how something should be displayed is up to your view. Your controller should only return status codes and then your view should decide what to do.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i would agree with you if the validation can be checked by the view itself such as Required, length, or even if it can be checked using the "Remote" data annotation,,, but in my case how the view can know if the object that is currently displayed in the view has been added by another system user unless the server return an exception ....

Comment: What are you doing with the partial view on the client? Using some Javascript to put it in a div or something? What if you would change the return type to ActionResult and then return a ViewModel with the properties HasErrors, ErrorMessage and PartialViewHtml? Then in your Javascript you can check if there are errors and then choose to display the error message or display the partial view.

Comment: but in my case how i can return a Java script alert incase an exception was raised , other than tying my implementation to the user interface

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning inline js you should have error handling code on your client side within a js library. Rather than returning the hole js only return the message.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd say yes.  But, sometimes a bad design is just what the doctor ordered ;)

There's a Controller instance method called `Javascript` that I use to return executable javascript from my controller, on very limited occasions, when taking the time to do it the "right" way isn't feasible:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Register(string id, int classid) 
{
    try
    {
        ... stuff
    }
    catch (DataException ex)
    { 
        return Javascript("alert('The user might have been already Assinged, Search Again to get the latest users');");
    }
}
```

The fact that something like this exists gives me solace that I'm not completely breaking the law.. unless I'm using it wrong, which I probably am.